# Unable to see the live Video in DirectShowLib

Tags: c#, desktop-application, directshow, directshow.net, wia

I have downloaded the source code from https://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/DirectShowSamples/2010-February/

**Samples\Capture\DxSnap**

when i run the code i'm unable to see the live video. The top screen is blank. If i click the button it can able to capture the current image.

I have checked with integrated camera and External camera. Both gives me same result.
I use DELL integrated cam and Logic External cam. Attached screenshot below.

Please let me know i'm missing something or not.

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Are you running this on a "second monitor" or using remote desktop? I have had trouble making previews appear in those situations